# form element attribute change doesn't affect submitted data

Tags: forms

I'm trying to change an attribute of form element after it was rendered and delivered to browser, by manually editing html document (in chrome developer). For example:

```
        $element['username'] = array (
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('Enter something'),
                '#attributes' => array ( 'some_attr' => array ('1')),
                '#ajax' => array (
                        'callback' => '_ajax_callback',
                        'wrapper' => 'uid_replace_me',
                        'keypress' => TRUE, # to strike callback on enter
                ),
        );
```

if I change the attribute **some_attr** in browser manually to something random (actual problem involves attribute change by javascript as part of ajax callback), and trigger callback function as:

```
_ajax_callback(&$form, &$form_state)
```

dumping the **$form_state** still shows that the attribute wasn't changed. I've spent few hours already trying to discover why... : \ Seeking for community help.